# python errno 99/unknow interface

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

I was studying "how to build a simple network sniffer" but I have a lot of problems.
I created two scripts (really easy), but in both of these I get an error every time.

First script:

```
import socket
import os
import struct
from ctypes import *

host = "192.168.1.37"

class IP(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ihl",           c_ubyte, 4),
        ("version",       c_ubyte, 4),
        ("tos",           c_ubyte),
        ("len",           c_ushort),
        ("id",            c_ushort),
        ("offset",        c_ushort),
        ("ttl",           c_ubyte),
        ("protocol_num",  c_ubyte),
        ("sum",           c_ushort),
        ("src",           c_ulong),
        ("dst",           c_ulong),
]

def __new__(self, socket_buffer=None):
    return self.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)

def __init__(self, socket_buffer=None):

    self.protocol_map = {1:"ICMP", 6:"TCP", 17:"UDP"}

    self.src_address = socket.inet_ntoa(
        struct.pack("<L",self.src))
    self.dst_address = socket.inet_ntoa(
        struct.pack("<L",self.dst))

if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP

sniffer = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET,
    socket.SOCK_RAW,
    socket_protocol)

sniffer.bind((host, 0))

sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
try:
    while true:

        raw_buffer = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]

        ip_header = IP(raw_buffer[0:20])

        print ("Protocol: %s %s -> %s") % (ip_header.protocol, \
               ip_header.src_adress, ip_header.dst_adress)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if os.name == "nt":
        sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

When I execute on my Android device I get this error:
`errno 99 invalid address` (I changed the host address a lot of times but nothing happened)

Second code: (really easy with Scapy)

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = sniff(iface="eth0", count=10)
```

When I try to execute this code I get this error:
`unknown network interface "eth0"` (or wlan0 ecc..)

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this on an Android device, maybe the eth0 interface doesn’t exist / is not available.

You can try `get_if_list()` to see what interfaces are available (scapy)